# Tensorflow can't invert matrix while using Gradient Descent Optimizer

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm using `tf.linalg.det`, and I'm optimizing a function using `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`. When I try to minimize my loss, but I get an error:

```
Input is not invertible.[[Node: 
gradients_14/MatrixDeterminant_14_grad/MatrixInverse = 
MatrixInverse[T=DT_FLOAT, adjoint=true, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]
(TensorArrayStack_14/TensorArrayGatherV3)]]
```

Here is a sample matrix that I calculate the determinant of:

```
cov_mat = [[24133534. 15928681. 18767914. 12779963.]
 [15928681. 22415040. 16570539. 13000952.]
 [18767914. 16570539. 21845432. 12702288.]
 [12779963. 13000952. 12702288. 24759624.]]
```

When I try to find the inverse using numpy:

`inv_matrix = np.linalg.inv(cov_mat)`

I get

```
inv_matrix = [[ 1.3129764e-07 -1.9006050e-08 -9.2320363e-08 -1.0428365e-08]
[-1.9006050e-08  1.1152212e-07 -5.6890045e-08 -1.9562632e-08]
[-9.2320363e-08 -5.6890045e-08  1.7552667e-07 -1.2525011e-08]
[-1.0428365e-08 -1.9562632e-08 -1.2525011e-08  6.2468771e-08]]
```

Multiplying the inverse matrix by original matrix in numpy, I get something close to an identity matrix:

```
np.dot(cov_mat,inv_matrix)) = 
[[ 1.0000001e+00 -1.2194361e-07  7.6666574e-08  4.2256303e-08]
[ 5.1060049e-08  9.9999994e-01  1.6705408e-07  4.1031740e-08]
[ 9.1811515e-08 -9.5680974e-08  1.0000004e+00  1.5748128e-08]
[-1.8350470e-08  1.3953368e-08  1.4236801e-07  1.0000000e+00]]
```

Can anyone give me any insight as to why tensorflow can't compute the gradient?

Edit: So I figured out that if I only run the optimizer for one iteration, I get a gradient, but if I run the optimizer for more than 1 iteration, I get the non-invertible matrix error.

Comment: Which matrix do you want to invert? the cov_mat?

Comment: Yes, the cov_mat, since the gradient of the determinant involves an inverse matrix. I can get the gradient for the first iteration, but after that, I can't invert the matrix anymore.

Comment: Could you give us the code of the loss function you are trying to minimize ?

Comment: @RebeccaChen Did you ever figure out the issue ? I'm currently getting the same non-invertible matrix error after one iteration.